# Why this sorting visualisation is so slow?

Tags: java, sorting, graphics

Yesterday I saw some cool videos about comparing sorting algorithms. I've decided to write the same but just after start I found that this sorting visualization is incredibly slow. With this code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class ViewSort extends JFrame implements Runnable{
    private int N = 100;
    private int max = 500;
    private int[] array;
    private Thread th;
    private DrawPanel drawPanel;
    long startTime;
    int iter = 0;

    public ViewSort(){
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        this.setSize(N*2 + 50, max + 50);
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Stupid Sort Viewer");
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        this.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);
        array = generateArray(N, max);
        th = new Thread(this);
        th.start();
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public static int[] generateArray(int N, int max){
        int[] array = new int[N];
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            array[i] = (int) (Math.random() * max);
        }
        return array;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0; i < N - 1; i++){
            iter++;
            if(array[i] > array[i + 1]){
               int tmp = array[i];
               array[i] = array[i + 1];
               array[i + 1] = tmp;
               i = 0;
            }
            try{
                th.sleep(1);
            }catch(InterruptedException ie){
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
            drawPanel.repaint();
        }
        System.out.print((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000 / 1000 / 1000);
        System.out.print(" seconds left on ");
        System.out.print(iter);
        System.out.print(" iterations on sorting an array of ");
        System.out.print(N);
        System.out.print(" integers");
    }

    private void printArray(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            sb.append(array[i]);
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        System.out.println(new String(sb));
    }

    class DrawPanel extends JPanel{            
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
                g.fillRect(i*2 + 25, getHeight() - array[i], 2, array[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                new ViewSort().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

With that code I have output like
**170 seconds left on 116441 iterations on sorting an array of 100 integers**
P.S.
I know that sort is slowest (except random sort) but not so!

Comment: Get rid of the `paintChildren` method and place the logic in the `paintComponent` method.  Call `super.paintComponent` before you do any custom painting

Comment: @MadProgrammer super.paintComponent in constructor with which argument?

Comment: Call `super.paintComponent(g);` at the start of your `paintComponent` method

Comment: @MadProgrammer that does not make sense. Result now is `143 seconds left on 112137 iterations on sorting an array of 100 integers`

Comment: You're performing custom painting wrong, I don't know if that will effect the performance, but it prevent other possible issues from occuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i = 0;
```

You have two problems, both caused by the above line:

1) Every time you find two number out of order you go back to 0 and redo the comparison. But if you swap the 24 and 25 values, you already know the values before 24 were correct, so you only need to go back and compare the 23 and 24 values.

2) You set the value to zero, but then the for loop increments "I" by one so you only ever start comparing at index 1, so the first value will always be out of order (unless it randomly happens to be the smallest value).

You can fix both problems by using:

```
i = Math.max(-1, i - 2);
```

Note:

Although the class will work with the painting code in the paintChildren() method that code really should be moved to the paintComponent() method as suggested by MadProgrammer. Custom painting should be done in the paintComponent() method. The paintChildren() method is used by Swing to paint Swing components added to the panel.

Comment: This question is not about sort. 
I put all graphics in paintComponent it's start and result is like 5% better.
BTW: that sort really sorting array for 4341178 NANOS.

Comment: @Aero, it is about the sort. Your code sleeps for every iteration of the loop that you do. You are doing `116441` iterations which means you need 117 seconds for the code to run because you sleep for 1ms every iteration. Then you need time to repaint the Graphics 117441 times. Reduce the number of iterations and you reduce the sort time.

Comment: Graphics - 170000000000 nanos, non-graphics - 4341178 nanos. Graphics make it 39159.8 times slower. I'm askng about that massive overload.

Comment: Of course Graphics takes more time than CPU code to do your comparisons. Why are you surprised by this? Anytime you deal with hardware (like the video screen, or reading data from a file) the processing time will take longer then just executing a simple code algorithm. When you do simple comparisons you are executing a single line of code. Do you think painting to the screen is a single line of code or maybe thousands of lines of code? The solution is to reduce the number of paint requests, which is done by the solution I gave you.

Comment: @aero. Try your suggestion and see what happens. One of the most common problems in programming is "boundary issues". Either an index too small or too big.